# Download Word document from the link in R

Tags: r

I am trying to download a Word document with R.Document is on the following link and can be easily downloadable only with a click. To download this document, I wrote the following code :

```
url = "https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/tedb/exportTax.html?taxId=4205&taxVersionDate=1672527600"

path<-"C:/"

download.file(url,path)
```

But unfortunately, although the document can be downloaded only with on click, this code doesn't work as expected, and I can't download the document. So can anybody help me how to solve this problem and download a Word document?

Comment: When asking questions on SO about code that generates errors, you need to include the literal error text, please don't ask us to get that far just to see the clear problem. Additionally, when you have a problem with a function and it does not behave as expected, I urge you to read its documentation. In this case, [`?download.file`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/download.file.html) says that its second argument is `destfile`, emphasis on ***file***. Change `path` to a _filename_ and not a directory. And btw, I am getting HTML here, not a doc file.

Comment: I tried with these lines: dest_file <- "tax_data1.doc"
download.file(url,dest_file) and I downloaded file. But the file probably is something different than the Word file, although have that extension. How to proceed with this? I want to import this file inside in R, but this additionally complicated things

Answer (score 2):

`download.file` is not going to work, it appears that the remote website checks the connection `USER_AGENT` and does not accept the user agent offered by R. Namely, on my windows system, the user agent appears to be `libcurl/7.83.1`, it might be slightly different on unix/macos systems (or older versions of R). (Side note: I'm surprised by this, since `download.file` says that it uses `options("HTTPUserAgent")` for this which resolves to `"R (4.2.3 x86_64-w64-mingw32 x86_64 mingw32)"`, but when I tested it on a remote site, the remote reported the libcurl agent.)

We can use `httr` for this:

```r
library(httr)
res <- GET(url,
  write_disk("foo.doc"),
  user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/111.0"))
```

and `"foo.doc"` is your DOC file.

FYI, I found *this* user-agent by googling `what is my user agent`. I suspect there are a myriad of values that the remote webserver will accept and return the "real" file instead of an html page.

Comment: This gives the same result similar as my code above dest_file <- "tax_data1.doc" download.file(url,dest_file) and download data in DOC file. But the problem is that file does not file that I download by clicking on the link, which is a Word document with an extension docx.After downloading, I want to import file again inside in R and extract each table from the document with the library(docxtractr). But unfortunately, I can't because this is more similar to some HTML file than docx

Comment: I see. I agree that it is _really_ HTML and not a DOC file. This means that the website is wrong by suggesting a `.doc` file extension versus the point that the contents are raw HTML. There's nothing you can do in R if the website does this to you. Perhaps rename to `.html` and try to parse it as such? (`rvest` might be better if ultimately you need to extract a table from it.)

Comment: I tried Rvest. That was the first option. Now I tried a second :)

Comment: This is interesting! `download.file()` worked for me on Ubuntu. I was able to use this to get the file: `download.file(url = "https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/tedb/exportTax.html?taxId=4205&taxVersionDate=1672527600",
                      destfile = "taxdoc.doc")` . The file also appears to be a relatively normal `.doc` file.

Comment: Please confirm @Russ, on the shell command line, `file taxdoc.doc` returns something other than `HTML`? For me, it returns `foo.doc: HTML document, UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines, with CRLF, LF line terminators`

Comment: Oh, no you're right, same thing :D